# iPhone App Close immediately after launching

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an iPhone app and working fine . But some of(2 or 3) my customers arises a complaint that they are having issue opening the app in the iPhone . They have installed the app and when open the app it just closes out right away. Also tried restarting  phone but it still does this.Also tried to delete the app and then reinstall it but this still happens. 
Is this any thing i can do in my app to prevent this ? Or how they can solve this problem ?

Comment: That may be the initial crash. On which version your customer are having this issue? That might be they are using latest iOS version but your app may not be compatible with that version.

Comment: Do you have any crash reporting frameworks in your app..?

Comment: update your app with latest version of iOS then release a new version of your app

Comment: use Crashlytics to detect crashed and check first iOS version which app is crashing

Comment: Did you give them as Adhoc build? if yes, your customer needs to trust the profile from General setting->device management

Answer (score -2):

Is there any more information you could give regarding the nature of the crash? Have you recreated this scenario in Xcode and gotten an error message?

The best I can think to tell you is to look in the app delegate. That is where your app looks first, so there is some kind of uncaught error happening.

Maybe the app is trying to use some piece of data right at launch and it's not there. Maybe you are trying to use something before it is initialized.

Is your app using any 3rd party frameworks right at launch? If so, maybe something changed with the library.

If it is happening on some iPhones and not others, perhaps you are using some framework or function that is not compatible with an older version of iOS.

Perhaps there is something in common among the kind of devices the app crashes on.

Another thought, does your app ask for any permissions? Such as using the user's location. If it does, and there is a spot in your code where you assume you have permission and you don't perhaps that could cause a crash.

Hope this helps.

P.S. just read the comments to your question. They have some good advice. I would try what they are suggesting.